# Getting error in resolving ionic tags in visual studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, ionic-view

I have created a blank cordova app (typescript) in VS 2015. I have installed the angularjs and ionic framework with their typed definition files.

The Ionic framework created the two html files, inside the template folder. After that, I have created a new test.html file inside the template folder and copy pasted the content of one of the generated html. In the test.html, I am getting the error "can not resolve ion-content (example)". I am getting this for all ionic directives. But I am not getting the same in the default generated html.
I am using Re sharper. I have stopped the resharper intellisense for html file, but that did not work. I am new to ionic, can you please tell me what I missed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Ionic Pack (tools and extensions). An extension to make you more productive working with the Ionic Framework

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d6279fba-bcff-4857-906d-29faa8a99448/

Comment: The Ionic Pack is providing very good intellisense for ionic tags. I am enjoying this pack. But some how it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Are you getting the same issue "can not resolve ion-content" -- or do you have a different issue?

Comment: The same issue and blue underline for all the ionic tags.

Comment: Suspending the resharper have solved this issue, I think there was some problem with suspending for html files before.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to just use the command line and a text editor, as this gives you much more control over your project. You can follow the guide here:

http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

I have tried working with Visual Studio, but it just didn't work out for me. I guess most of the community is also working with the command line interface and a text editor, so there is not very much support for Visual Studio (could be wrong here)